# Dictionary () as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using a dictionary variable to match up a drop and drag exercice.

```
var dict = new Dictionary ();
dict[box_a]=s1;
dict[box_b]=s2;
dict[box_c]=s3;
dict[box_d]=s4;
```

question 1: at the end i would like to check if box_a== with s1 and so on .... how would I do that

```
for each( var item  in dict)
    {   item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
    if(item==????)
// what do i have to put instead of ???
    hits=hits+1;
```

question 2:I would like box_d to accept also s3 how would i do that 
if i do 
 dict[box_d]=s4; and  dict[box_d]=s3; it wont work because it matches it with the last equal. :( 
Thanks !!

Comment: What are s* variables (s1, s2 etc.)? Are you not keeping references to them in the code (you are creating them and not storing the references anywhere but in the `dict` variable)? Could you provide more context (more code) to what you're doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Intro

A Dictionary is a collection of key/value, is like a table:

```
+------+--------+
| key1 | value1 |
+------+--------+
| key2 | value2 |
+------+--------+
| key3 | value3 |
+------+--------+
| key4 | value4 |
+------+--------+
```

To access the values you must use the keys i.e: `dict[key2]` returns `value2`

### Answer 1:

You can't access the keys directly, buy you can use a `for ()` statement to access them, so this:

```
for (var key:* in dict) {
    trace('dict[' + key + '] = ' + dict[key]);
}
```

will output this:

```
dict[key1] = value1
dict[key2] = value2
dict[key3] = value3
dict[key4] = value4
```

You are using a `for each ()` statement. With that particular statement you have another result, because you are iterating through the values and not the keys, so this:

```
for each (var value:* in dict) {
    trace(value);
}
```

will output this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

So if you want to check something with a key you must use the `for (key in dict)` form.

### Answer 2:

I recommend you to use Arrays like this:

```
dict[box_a] = [s1];
dict[box_b] = [s2];
dict[box_c] = [s3];
dict[box_d] = [s3, s4];
```

and then access the values as arrays and check with all of the values:

```
for (var key:* in dict) {
    var values:Array = dict[key];
    for each (var value:* in values) {
        // do what you want with s1, s2, s3, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million great explaining !!

Comment: If I need to see if the object in box_a is s1 how would i do that ?for (var key:* in dict){ 
if( key == dict[key])
{hits=hits+1;}

 }

Comment: P.s Those keys and dict[keys] are movieclips

Comment: Yes you should do something like that: key == dict[key] if you want to know if the value of the key is the key itself.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like equality can be checked only for primitive types, replacing `==` operator with `===` changes nothing:

```
        var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        dict['ololo1'] = { one : 1, two : '2' };
        dict[ { one : 1, two : '2' } ] = function(o:*):String { return o as String; };
        dict[function(o:*):String { return o as String; }] = 'ololo';
        dict['ololo2'] = 'ololo2';
        dict[{ one : 1, two : '2' }] = { one : 1, two : '2' };
        for (var key:* in dict) {
            trace(key, dict[key], key == dict[key]); 
        }
        trace('equal functions :', (function(o:*):String { return o as String; } === 
                                    function(o:*):String { return o as String; } ));
        trace('equal objects :', ({ one : 1, two : '2' } === 
                                  { one : 1, two : '2' } ));
        trace('equal functions :', (function(o:*):String { return o as String; } == 
                                    function(o:*):String { return o as String; } ));
        trace('equal objects :', ({ one : 1, two : '2' } == 
                                  { one : 1, two : '2' } ));

        var obj:Object = { one : 1, two : '2' };
        var obj1:Object = { one : 1, two : '2' };
        var fun:Function = function(o:*):String { return o as String; };
        var fun1:Function = function(o:*):String { return o as String; };
        trace(obj == { one : 1, two : '2' }, 
              obj == obj1,
              fun == function(o:*):String { return o as String; },
              fun == fun1);
```

outputs

```
[object Object] [object Object] false
function Function() {} ololo false
[object Object] function Function() {} false
ololo2 ololo2 true
ololo1 [object Object] false
equal functions : false
equal objects : false
equal functions : false
equal objects : false
false false false false
```

however, `obj == obj` returns `true` ;)